# Extend index structures of HSQLDB

Tags: java, hsqldb

**Do you think it is possible to extend the index structures of HSQLDB 2.0?**

I've seen that HSQLDB implements AVL trees, but I'm not sure if I can extend that by e.g. implementing R-trees in the HSQLDB code. Are the index structures in HSQLDB even materialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to develop an R-tree implementation of index for HSQLDB. But to make use of such indexes additional query syntax is also required.

The index structures for CACHED tables (disk based tables) are persisted.